# SSRS Report runs in VS 2008 preview Hangs in Browser

Tags: reporting-services

Absolute newbie to SSRS, so please bear with me.

I have a report that will run when using the Preview tab in Visual Studio no matter what criteria I enter for one of the parameters.

However when it is deployed, viewing the report in any browser I use (IE 7,8,9, Firefox and Chrome), the report will only show results when I select certain people for said parameter.

When it doesn't work in the browser, it will show the loading spinner and display some results grayed out. If I leave the report loading for several minutes (about 10min is the most I have tried so far) and then cancel the loading, I can still see the data that it has loaded, but my print button and other controls apart from refresh are disabled.

I'm not sure what version the report was designed in/for, but I believe it was pre 2008 R2.

The report server is running SQL server 2008 R2.

I have also checked that the query run by the report when viewed in the browser works by tracing it and running it in SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, but solved it by removing "Keep together" as an option on my tables to allow multi-page rendering.

Any other area where "Keep together" is set (groups, pages) to attempt to render things in a single page should be unchecked for items to render in multipule pages without freezing the browser.